# How to add Twenty Twenty(Image Before & After) in magento2.4.2

Tags: css, frontend, magento2.4.2

I need to add a picture comparison function. This is the code [Twenty Twenty](https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) I need, it looks very good, and it's free. But we don't know how to make it run.

Twenty Twenty Download Link https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

Thank you everyboby.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to call js file properly.

> Step 1:- Please create file default.xml under path
> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/

Add below code in your xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.js" template="Magento_Theme::js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 2:- Now, please create file js.phtml file under path
> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/templates/

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery.event.move', 
        'jquery.twentytwenty',
        'custom',
    ]);
</script>
```

> Step 3:- Add your js file in path app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME
> NAME HERE}}/default/web/js

> Step 4:- Add your css in path app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/web/css/twentytwenty.css

Above will work for any custom js/css.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the library by including it with require js:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'twentyTwenty': 'Vendor_Twentytwenty/js/twentytwenty/jquery.twentytwenty',
        'twentyTwentyInit': 'Vendor_Twentytwenty/js/twentytwenty/twentytwenty.init'
    },
},
deps: [
]};
```

next create the init:

```
define([
'jquery',
'twentyTwenty'], function ($) {
'use strict';
return function (options, el) { // for declarative notation
     
     $("#container1").twentytwenty();
}; });
```

and you can use it like this

```
data-mage-init='{"twentyTwentyInit":{}}'>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround for replacement. Just use the Slider Revolution plugin.
[image]